# how to show a category of woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How can I display the products of a category in my woocommerce theme ?

I'm going to design a woocommerce template and I want it in it display the products of a category .

For example : T-shirt category or ... .

Comment: woocommerce by default provides this facility, you can add your categories in admin from following steps: apperance-> menus-> add menu from product category option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code taken from Woo's github https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/meta.php

```
global $product
echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```